# setFetchSize() on mysql above 5.0.3?

Tags: mysql

Mysql documentation says

> When using versions of the JDBC driver earlier than 3.2.1, and connected to server versions earlier than 5.0.3, the setFetchSize() method has no effect, other than to toggle result set streaming

What about after 5.0.3? Can I use `setFetchSize(100)` now? Will it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will indeed work if you also set the JDBC [option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) `useCursorFetch` for the connection.

However, due to the way MySQL implements server-side cursors, you will have to wait for the query to complete on the server before results arrive, and you will consume additional memory server-side.